# UVs button is missing

Tags: texturing, uv, export

I want to export the UV layout of a mesh but I can't seem to find the UVs menu in the image window to save the UV face layout (according to the [blender wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Mapping/UV/Applying_Image)). I could of course use the plain [command](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.ops.uv.html) but that seems like a bit of a workaround, and there is also a lot more in that UVs menu that I'm not able to acces.

edit: the switch to edit mode did it

Comment: Do you see the UV layout in the window? The UV-editor also is an image viewer and editor. It also shows the render result.

Comment: Hit spacebar then search **Export UV layout**. Good luck. However, this menu will only show up when in Edit mode. If you are certain about this, I suggest you at least upload a screenshot or demo file link, to have others convinced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have unwrapped an object and you are in edit mode (so that you can see the unwrapped object in the UV editor) there should be an UV menu. Here a three screenshots to show how it should look.

[image: Here should the UV menu be]
[image: The export option in the UV menu]
[image: The export dialog]